# Reactjs - Acces url Image via JSON file

Tags: reactjs

I used create-react-app to create my project.
I am trying to display images based on a JSON file but it don't show up.

I have my JSON datas located in app(root) > public > datas > file.json
I have my images in app > src > assets > images > myimage.jpg

There is one object of my JSON file :

```
{
"name": "Centre de thérapie manuelle",
"imageUrl": "/assets/images/centredetherapiemanuelle.jpg",
"category": "Professionnel",
"description": "Site vitrine réalisé à partir du CMS d'entreprise",
"role": "Intégration de la maquette via le CMS d'entreprise, responsive",
"url": "https://www.centredetherapiemanuelle.lu/fr/kinesitherapie",
"technologies": ["html5", "css3", "sass", "bootstrap"]
```

and there is my JSON call :

```
    const Projects = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('/datas/projects.json')
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error : ', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <section id="projects" className="section container projects-section">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-12">
          <h2>Projets</h2>
          <ul className="projects-container">
            {data.map((projet, index) => (
              <ProjectsInsert key={index} projet={projet} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

And where I create my image :

```
const ProjectsInsert = ({ projet }) => {
  return (
    <li>
      <div className="img-container">
        <img src={projet.imageUrl} alt={projet.name} />
      </div>
      <div className="infos-container">
        <h4>{projet.name}</h4>
        <h5>{projet.category}</h5>
        <p>{projet.description}</p>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" href={projet.url}>
          Visiter le site
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

I verify the path, the name of my image severals times, it just don't show up.

I tried with

```
const [imageURLs, setImageURLs] = useState([]);




useEffect(() => {
    const urls = data.map((project) => project.imageUrl);
    setImageURLs(urls);
  }, [data]);

{data.map((projet, index) => (
              <ProjectsInsert
                key={index}
                projet={projet}
                imageURL={imageURLs[index]}
              />

return (
  <section id="projects" className="section container projects-section">
    <h2>Projets</h2>
    <ul>
      {data.map((project, index) => (
        <ProjectsInsert key={index} projet={project} imageUrl={imageURLs[index]} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  </section>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing the first slash in the imageUrl path in your JSON file so it would be:

```
"imageUrl": "assets/images/centredetherapiemanuelle.jpg",
```

I believe everything else is fine

Comment: Thx for your answer but it doesn't work. :(